# How to share my mobile broadband connection via Wifi

Tags: android, network-bridge, hot-spot

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop having wifi. I have an android tablet which has wifi support. I connect my laptop to the internet through Mobile broadband (reliance netconnect zte modem). I need to know how to share that connection to my tablet through wifi...

Answer (score 1):

[Connection Sharing Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing)

In particular:

> GUI Method via Network Manager (Ubuntu 12.04) Open
>   Settings->Network->Wireless and create a new Ad Hoc network. To use a
>   common denominator for all devices choose WEP for security and create
>   a 5 letters password from 0..9A..F. Note that this a least secure
>   encryption standard.

Answer (score 1):

Answer tested just now on Ubuntu 16.04.4

Sharing mobile broadband via GUI doesn't work, use iptables.

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing...iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#Ubuntu_Internet_Gateway_Method_.28iptables.29)

don't forget to flush previous rules.

run

```
ifconfig
```

output

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:aa:12:12:12:12  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:7034 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7034 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:587608 (587.6 KB)  TX bytes:587608 (587.6 KB)

aph0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:aa:12:12:12:12  
      inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: de20::de20:de20:de20:de20/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:15418 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:23654 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1197965 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:31685740 (31.6 MB)

mobBd0     0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:aa:12:12:12:12  
      inet addr:104.25.38.26  Bcast:104.25.38.27  Mask:255.255.255.252
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:47103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:29911 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:56188453 (56.1 MB)  TX bytes:2781129 (2.7 MB)
```

mobBd0 - mobile broadband (internet connection)

aph0 - wireles (internal network) on subnet 192.168.1.*

correct line 6 and line 9

```
...-o mobBd0 -i aph0 -s 192.168.1.0/24...

...POSTROUTING -o mobBd0 -j...
```

...in the script below

Here is a script for the above ifconfig output, run it with

```
user@my-computer:~/Desktop$  sudo ./name.sh
```

name.sh content

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables --flush            # Flush all the rules in filter and nat tables
iptables --table nat --flush
iptables --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --delete-chain
iptables -A FORWARD -o mobBd0 -i aph0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o mobBd0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables.sav
sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
```

Edit /etc/rc.local and add the following lines before the "exit 0" line:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.sav
```

The /etc/sysctl.conf edit is required because of a bug...
From 10.10 onwards, it suffices to edit /etc/sysctl.conf and uncomment:

```
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

... so that it reads:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

[Client setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#Client_set_up)
check if it works

```
ping google.com.
```

if it doesn't, try setting dns on client

```
8.8.8.8
```

if that works check dns settings on the host.

From here you can configure dhcp.